# How to achieve Async nonblocking call for dependent task in java springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency, reactive-programming, completable-future

I am generating excel file and giving it to UI. Excel file contains data from two third party apis. First third party call will return list of data and then I have compare this data from database table and after comparing I need to call second third party api
so second third party api is called each time based on data return from first third party call
like 100 records return from first third party call then second third party call 100 times.
How can I use concurrency in this because tasks are dependent

I have controller.java file which call service method and return excel file as a response and UI is downloading

### Controller.java

```
@GetMapping("/api/report")
public ResponseEntity < InputStreamResource > generateReport(
    @ApiParam("fromDate") @RequestParam(value = "fromDate", required = false) String fromDate,
    @ApiParam("toDate") @RequestParam(value = "toDate", required = false) String toDate) throws Exception {
    InputStreamResource isr = null;
    ByteArrayInputStream
    export = null;
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(fromDate) || StringUtils.isBlank(toDate)) {
        throw new Exception(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), "from date and to date is required");
    }
    List < DateRange > dateRangeList = convertToListOfDateRangeObj(fromDate, toDate);
    export = service.generateReport(dateRangeList);
    isr = new InputStreamResource(
        export);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Report.xls");
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(isr);
}
```

### Service.java

```
`  public ByteArrayInputStream generateReport(List < DateRange > dateRangeList)
      throws ParseException, IOException, HttpStatusCodeException, JSONException {
          List <ExcelData> reportData = new ArrayList < > ();
          List <ExcelData> finalReportData = new ArrayList < > ();
          for (DateRange dateRange: dateRangeList) {
              reportData = getData(dateRange.getFromDate(), dateRange.getToDate());
              finalReportData.addAll(reportData);
          }
          //logic to generate excel (Apache POI) using data available in finalReportData list
          ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          workbook.write(outputStream);
          return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
 }`
  private List <ExcelData> getData(String from, String to)
      throws HttpStatusCodeException, UnsupportedEncodingException, JsonProcessingException, JSONException {
          List <Excel> excelDataList = new ArrayList < > ();
          List <ResponseData> dataDetails = new ArrayList < > ();
          ResponseData list = firstThirdpartyCall(from, to, null);

          for (ResponseData data: list.getData()) {
              dataDetails.add(data);
          }

          dataDetails = dataDetails.stream()
              .filter(s - > s.getName().indexOf("EA") == 0 || s.getName().indexOf("EE") == 0)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());

          List < String > matchingRecords = getMatchingRecordFromDB(
              dataDetails.stream().map(s - > s.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList()));

          dataDetails = dataDetails.stream().filter(s - > matchingRecords.contains(s.getName()))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());

          for (int i = 0; i < dataDetails.size(); i++) {
              Info usersObj = secondThirdpartyCall(dataDetails.get(i).getId());
              //further process like database calls business logic on usersObj
          }
          //After process, populating List<ExcelData> and returning
          return excelDataList;
      }
```

I also tried completable future, but other threads like restcall is working in background and main thread give response as empty excel file because data is still been process in other threads So I am not getting the output . I need to bring the response time of my api to few sec.

Any help will be  appreciated
Thanks